# Confused about compiler errors received using gcc

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I'm trying to compile this assignment I'm doing and I'm running into errors I'm not sure how to fix. Esepcially for  Here's my command line argument:

```
gcc HW3.c semaphore.o buffer.c -L. -lst -o test
```

The problem is that the `semaphor.h` file was given to us so there isn't anything inherently wrong in the class so it shouldn't be complaining there I don't think. I'm not sure how to reconcile the struct errors either. I'm not particularly proficient in C. Here's the error list:

```
    In file included from buffer.c:11:
semaphore.h:4: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘st_cond_t’
In file included from buffer.h:2,
                 from buffer.c:12:
semaphore.h:4: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘st_cond_t’
semaphore.h:5: error: conflicting types for ‘semaphore’
semaphore.h:5: note: previous declaration of ‘semaphore’ was here
semaphore.h:7: error: conflicting types for ‘down’
semaphore.h:7: note: previous declaration of ‘down’ was here
semaphore.h:8: error: conflicting types for ‘up’
semaphore.h:8: note: previous declaration of ‘up’ was here
semaphore.h:9: error: conflicting types for ‘createSem’
semaphore.h:9: note: previous declaration of ‘createSem’ was here
buffer.c: In function ‘init_buffer’:
buffer.c:20: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘createSem’
semaphore.h:9: note: expected ‘struct semaphore *’ but argument is of type ‘semaphore’
buffer.c:21: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘semaphore’ from type ‘void *’
buffer.c:23: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘createSem’
semaphore.h:9: note: expected ‘struct semaphore *’ but argument is of type ‘semaphore’
buffer.c:24: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘semaphore’ from type ‘void *’
buffer.c: In function ‘c_deposit’:
buffer.c:38: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘down’
semaphore.h:7: note: expected ‘struct semaphore *’ but argument is of type ‘semaphore’
buffer.c:41: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘up’
semaphore.h:8: note: expected ‘struct semaphore *’ but argument is of type ‘semaphore’
buffer.c: In function ‘c_remove’:
buffer.c:46: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘down’
semaphore.h:7: note: expected ‘struct semaphore *’ but argument is of type ‘semaphore’
buffer.c:49: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘up’
semaphore.h:8: note: expected ‘struct semaphore *’ but argument is of type ‘semaphore’
```

buffer.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "semaphore.h"
#include "buffer.h"

buffer *init_buffer(int size)
{

    buffer *new_Buffer;
    new_Buffer=malloc((sizeof(buffer)));

    createSem(new_Buffer->emptyBuffer, size);
    new_Buffer->emptyBuffer=malloc(sizeof(semaphore));

    createSem(new_Buffer->fullBuffer, 0);
    new_Buffer->fullBuffer=malloc(sizeof(semaphore));

    new_Buffer->chars=malloc(sizeof(char)*size);

    new_Buffer->size=size;

    new_Buffer->nextIn=0;
    new_Buffer->nextOut=0;

    return new_Buffer;
}

void c_deposit(buffer *buffer, char c)
{
    down(buffer->emptyBuffer);
    buffer->chars[buffer->nextIn]=c;
    buffer->nextIn=(buffer->nextIn+1)%buffer->size;
    up(buffer->fullBuffer);
}
int c_remove(buffer *buffer)
{
    int c;
    down(buffer->fullBuffer);
    c=buffer->chars[buffer->nextOut];
    buffer->nextOut=(buffer->nextOut+1)%buffer->size;
    up(buffer->emptyBuffer);
    return c;
}
```

buffer.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "semaphore.h"

typedef struct{
    semaphore emptyBuffer;
    semaphore fullBuffer;
    int nextIn;
    int nextOut;
    int size;
    char *chars;
}buffer;

void c_deposit(buffer *buffer, char c);
int c_remove(buffer *buffer);

buffer *init_buffer(int size);
```

For good measure here's semaphore.h as well:

```c
typedef struct
{
  int value;
  st_cond_t sem_queue;
} semaphore;

void down(semaphore *s);
void up(semaphore *s);
void createSem(semaphore *s, int value);
```

Comment: Where is `st_cond_t` defined?

Comment: probably  part of the `st.h` library that's included in my `main.c` I didn't post the `main.c` because none of the errors reference it

Comment: Consider your include dependencies: main.c #includes st.h;  buffer.c #includes buffer.h, which #includes semaphore.h.  But nowhere does buffer.c include st.h.  So somewhere along the chain, buffer.c needs to include st.h.  I would recommend you have semaphore.h #include st.h, since it is the file which directly requires the contents of st.h

Comment: Also the content of semaphore.h is effectively #included twice, hence the previous declaration warnings.  Good practice is to set your headers up to be [once-only headers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Once_002dOnly-Headers.html#Once_002dOnly-Headers), so they can be included many times without issue

Comment: okay, thanks! unfortunately adding `st.h` to `semaphore.h` doesn't help

Comment: after adding `st.h` to `semaphore.h` do you get the same set or a different set of errors?

Comment: It only worked after using `#pragma once`. It's odd because my code is almost identical to one of my classmates but his does not need it and he includes everything more than one time but the compiler doesn't complain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like semaphore.h needs to do this:

```
#include <st.h>
```

Also, you are including semaphore.h twice which is confusing the compiler.

Try putting this in semaphore.h as well:

```
#pragma once
```

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once

Comment: Is it okay to have `#include "buffer.h"` both in my `main.c` file and my `buffer.c` or is bad style as well?

Comment: Style is debatable, but the `#pragma once` will be needed in that header file as well.

Comment: If the contents of buffer.h are needed by what is in your main.c, then it will need to be included somehow, be it directly or indirectly